# Is it possible to batch processing in photoshop make resize the different size of images?

Tags: image-processing, photoshop

Is it possible to perform batch processing in Photoshop to resize images to different sizes at the same time?

Comment: Why Photoshop? Are other products off limits?

Comment: any softwares or other products. no limits.

Comment: You could try using [imagemagik](http://www.imagemagick.org)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/). It's free and you can use Python to script it (and it allows performing actions like resizing).

As far as Photoshop is concerned why don't you just group the images in to folders depending on what size you want them and then batch process each folder?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with Photoshop is to either set one axis to the same size on all the images, or perform a stop after the action runs each time so you can manually resize the photo to the correct dimensions.

The first option doesn't sound like what you want, and the second option won't save you much time. Using two folders sounds like the best option, assuming you've only got two different dimensions of photo to resize.